# help developing web based multiplayer game

Tags: x3d

i want to develop a web based multi player game. how can i use x3d format to make such game? or will i stick to standard download and play type game usually written in c++?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a 3D game for the web, you should definitely have a look at http://unity3d.com/